# MVC3 : different validation for different input scenarios

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, yii

I have used [yii](/questions/tagged/yii) framework in php extensively and find [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/) very useful. 
to summarize, scenarios let you have different validation criteria for different views.

**Question**

Can I use mvc3 built in validation and yet have different validation criteria for different views .Is there a built in function for this?

**Explanation**

In one of the forms I only want to validate change of password, in another form I just want to validate new user parameters, yet another place only requires validation of some detailed data input. All values are stored in the same table but need different input value sets

Comment: You should look into using strongly typed view-models to wrap your data in. These can hold the validations you require on a per need basis.

Comment: Agree with Travis, if you want to have different validation logic for different views, you should create a separate view model for each. http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#BM_Model_Validation_Improvements

Comment: interesting, it seems I need to use IValidatableObject.. lets c what I can find about that

Comment: As everyone suggested use different ViewModels for different views, that way your view is clean (no logic only presentation) and your classes (view models) take single responsibility. As a suggestion you can try FluentValidation http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: ok it seems that the option  is to use different viewModels for each view (kinda bulky but a lot less logic and performance friendly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the built in framework validation is attribute based, it makes it difficult to change validation requirements at run time if you're sharing models across views.

As such, your best bet would be to create different models for each view.

If you need to have custom validation applied at run time to your models then you can use http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

It's not built in, but works with the existing ASP.NET MVC validation components and as such can be used with unobtrusive validation / model state etc.

Comment: FluentValidation seems to be a nice choice too, however I have used multiple classes per view to solve my case. I guess the right answer to my question is up there... == NO , you can't have scenarios in asp.net, not in a simple way that is.